# environmental variable value not being processed

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, mailchimp

I am still learning about env. I'm not sure why it's not working. I have two files in my root project folder. '.env.local' and '.env'. And, the values for .env aren't being processed. However, .env.local is working fine. I believe I followed the same format.

For the .env file, if I just write them on the page and expose them, then they work just fine.

What am I missing here, this is on a NEXTJS app. In vercel I just added Environmental variable to their built in mechanism.

In my code I wrote this to get the value.

env local file

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE=xxxxxxxxxx
```

_app.js

my env file 

    MAILCHIMP_PUBLIC_USERNAME=xxxxx
    MAILCHIMP_PUBLIC_DOMAIN=xxxx
    MAILCHIMP_PUBLIC_POST=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&
    MAILCHIMP_PUBLIC_ID=xxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `.env.local` is overriding the other files. Also remember to add `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to the variables. After editing the `.env` file you should stop and restart the development server. In your case you should do the following

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILCHIMP_PUBLIC_USERNAME=xxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILCHIMP_PUBLIC_DOMAIN=xxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILCHIMP_PUBLIC_POST=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILCHIMP_PUBLIC_ID=xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: i got rid of the .local file and now just have one .env.development - my google analytics key is working fine. But, the other values for mailchimp aren't being processed.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Check that all MailChimp variables are correct and that you're not using strings where you should be using a number. You can also do this if you saved a number as a string in the `.env` file `Number(String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILCHIMP_ID))`. If all variables are correct then try to stop the developement server, clear the browser cache and delete `.next` cache folder and restart.

Comment: THANK YOU!! that was the key - I missed Next_PUBLIC for the other values

Answer (score 0):

Did You read exactly the `next.js` [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) about `Environment Variables` ? ;-)

It happens because as we can read in `next.js` **docs**:

> In general only one .env.local file is needed. However, sometimes you
> might want to add some defaults for the development (next dev) or
> production (next start) environment.
>
> Next.js allows you to set **defaults** in .env (all environments),
> .env.development (development environment), and .env.production
> (production environment).
>
> **.env.local** **always overrides the defaults set**.

Here You have much more examples how to use `.env` properly in next.js. [source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/environment-variables), [source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/environment-variables/pages/index.js)

Good Luck and enjoy your study ;-)!

Comment: i got rid of the .local file and now just have one .env.development - my google analytics key is working fine. But, the other values for mailchimp aren't being processed.

Comment: @shar27 I gave You sources and best advises as I can. If You have new issue.. I suggest You add new question ;-) Remember add all of your code ! any errors and info's ;-) Good Luck and best regards !

Comment: @shar27
Notice that!!! how and where you use the variables is important  Environment variables are only available in the Node.js(serverside ) environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser. In order to expose a variable to the browser(clientside) you have to prefix the variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_.

Comment: @shar27 hint! check your sources ;-)